# Hibernate ServiceRegistryBuilder deprecated

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I can't use buildServiceRegistry because it's not defined, the import:

```
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
```

Is strikethrough

```
public SessionFactory open (){

        Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry sr= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);

        return sf;

}
```

What I need is the Session object, any alternatives?¿
And why can I use the same code on a Java Project but not on a Dynamic Web Proyect¿?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey seems I have answered myself, I don't know why it works, but works, despite the buildSessionFactory is strikthrough

```
public SessionFactory open (){

    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    return sf;

}
```